# Google Analytics vs Play services events

Tags: android, google-play-services

I noticed that google play services has Events. I was wondering why would some one user Events Vs Google analytics? How do you make the decision to use which or which?

Thank you

Comment: Which events in Play services are you referring to?  You should use GA (not Play Services regardless) if you are hoping to track user interaction events.

Comment: You can use **Google Play Games Events** service to collect cumulative data generated by your players during gameplay and store them in Google's servers for game analytics. Otherwise, use **Google Analytics** to collect, configure, and report on user-interactions with your online content.